# VBA paste special

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a script to copy entries from one worksheets cells into another one with a template. I am having issues setting merged cells to paste in non-merged cells. I have the following code, I know I can use Special Paste functions, but can I use more than one at a time? Would Paste:=xlColumnWidth help?

```
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("N6:O6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Reports").Select
    Range("O4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: hi travis does this work for you?  Worksheets("Reports").Range("O4") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("N6").MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Value

Comment: *I am having issues* --- what specific "issues"?

Comment: Good practice to try to avoid `Select` also to try and avoid the `Copy` using the clipboard. Does @James comment work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I'll just put this as an answer

```
Worksheets("Reports").Range("O4") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("N6").MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

**I agree with David about avoiding Selection** but the macro recorder produced the following:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("N6:O6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Reports").Select
    Range("O4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Which appears to work with **N6:O6** being merged..

Answer (score 0):

For a trivial amount of data like this no need to do something like this but good to be aware that `select` isn't needed much in `excel-vba` and also that the clipboard can be avoided:

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim vArr As Variant
vArr = Sheets("Reports").Range("N6:O6")

Dim Destination As Range
Set Destination = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("O4")
Destination.Resize(UBound(vArr, 1), UBound(vArr, 2)).Value = vArr

End Sub
```